# How can I get two non-physics actors to properly interact in Unreal Engine 4, causing one to "bounce?"

Tags: game-physics, actor, unreal-engine4

I am relatively new to Unreal, and I've been trying for a while now to get a "T Cell" entity I've blueprinted into Unreal to properly recognize a wall, before bouncing off of it akin to the old DVD screensaver. I've been trying quite a few methods, however all of them so far have either failed to work entirely or caused an incorrect bounce direction.

[This is what I would like to happen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoYDR.png) The T Cell is set to slowly "drift" towards the wall, and upon reaching it adjust its trajectory to bounce off of it. Neither are physics actors, as making either of them have physics messes up their states in several other ways.

Currently the impact is being read by a raytrace, [which is setup as shown here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygz6N.png) On the other hand, [this image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYoRK.png) depicts what occurs after the ray is cast. As is, the T Cell doesn't seem to recognize the wall at all, and simply phases through it. I suspect there is something wrong with how I am directing the raytrace, however I cannot be too sure. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think your line trace method over-complicates it. I would just use the OnComponentBeginOverlap event to trigger a bit of code to calculate a new direction for the T-cell to move in. Add an event for the selected object at the bottom of the Details panel.

See here:

[image: Blueprint Screenshot]

This example is extremely simple. All I'm doing is adding a small vector (DeltaLocation) to the sphere's position each tick. This vector is initially set to (1,1,0). The instant the sphere overlaps the wall*, I set the vector direction to (1,-1,0) so it moves off in the opposite direction in the y-axis. You'll want to do something better than that, with some basic geometry to calculate the angle.

Note the Collision options on the right. They're the same for the wall, except the wall's Object Type is 'WorldStatic' and in Object Responses 'World Static' is off and 'World Dynamic' is on. In Transform at the top, Mobility is set to Static for the wall. This is all so that the wall can detect the movable (dynamic) sphere, and the sphere can detect the static wall, so they know they've overlapped each other (and without making it do unnecessary work looking for other object types).

There's no actual physics going on here as collision is set to 'Query Only'.

*It will only overlap by a tiny, unnoticeable amount because, on the very next tick, it will be 'un-overlapped' because it's moved away. It could become problematic if the sphere is moving very fast, making the location change between ticks big, but 'Use CCD' can help with that (at the expense of CPU cycles).